# Votos negativos

Tags: soporte, votos-negativos

Recientemente, he estado leyendo comentarios de algunos usuarios del sitio, los cuales, con razón piden que cuando se haga *un voto negativo*, el usuario que lo haga emita su comentario para así poder entender en qué se ha equivocado. La persona y por supuesto que está corrija su error y gane en conocimiento.

He visto respuestas a esta interrogante que dice que el voto es *anónimo* y que debería de implementarse algo así como *comentarios anónimos*; cosa con la que estoy de acuerdo.

Mi pregunta en sí, es: ¿se está haciendo algo respecto a esto?

De ser así, ¿por dónde vamos?, o en caso contrario, ¿nos quedaremos igual?, ¿habrá solución?

Comment: no hay nada sobre esto en toda la red... asi que no, no se esta haciendo nada al respecto.

Comment: y entonces..............

Comment: no se esta haciendo nada en la red para esto... no se que mas queres que te diga.. podrias proponerlo en meta a ver que te dicen.. porque cualquiera de esos cambios son a nivel de red, no de este sitio...

Comment: ven aca y esto no es meta donde estoy publicando la inquietud

Comment: Esto es meta de Stackoverflow en español.. vos necesitas meta de la red... https://meta.stackexchange.com/... lo que vos pedis, es para toda la red...

Comment: Tu consulta no es algo de este sitio en particular, si no de todos los sitios en general.. se entiende?

Comment: si ya te copie tranquilo

Comment: estoy tranqui, perdon si no sono asi!

Comment: Yo pienso que la comunidad no respaldara esa petición(muchas pero muchas veces se ha pedido eso en SOen y siempre se declinó). Te recomiendo leer el post de meta del sitio en inglés donde la respuesta explica claramente porque no es obligatorio justificar cualquier voto: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not

Comment: Si alguien quiere darte consejos para mejorar los post no es necesario ser anónimo basta con escribirlo. El dar un DV o no, no te quita la posibilidad de señalarlo en los comentarios

Comment: Usualmente **yo**, no doy DV cuando el usuario es claramente nuevo en el sitio, al contrario le dejo un comentario con la invitación a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Sin embargo, cuando el usuario ya es veterano (100 o más puntos) le doy DV sin detenerme a dejar comentario si la pregunta la considero *insalvable*. Puedo dejar un comentario si la pregunta pudiera mejorarse según mi punto de vista, pero no más de allí. Claro, esta es mi opinión al respecto y en cuanto a tu sugerencia, mi opinión es que no debe ser obligatorio dejar comentario con DV, tal como no lo es para UV. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Japv ¿tu pregunta es a partir de que estas recibiendo votos negativos?, te entiendo, a veces es bueno saber en que nos equivocamos, yo te sugiero revisar [ask] y [answer], así como ver otras preguntas y respuestas del sitio que tienen buena puntuación, con eso puedes darte cuenta como realizar tus contribuciones.

Comment: Según lo que señalas quieres que los comentarios sean obligatorios ya que actualmente son voluntarios y eso es una mala idea, hace algunos días en SO habilitaron una encuesta en donde cuando dabas un DV te pedía *feedback* seleccionando opciones preestablecidas(con solo un click) y realmente fue molestoso

Comment: Hola @Japv. Estoy votando -1 en esta pregunta porque estoy radicalmente en contra y quiero poder votar -1 sin tener que dar explicaciones en _algunos_ casos.... Aunque ahora que lo pienso, ¿te imaginás qué pasaría si hubiese 50 comentarios parecidos al mío? -Totalmente irrelevante

Comment: Senores por favor de que estamos hablando, el objetivo principal de este sitio es aprender y si un usuario emite un voto negativo es logico que el que reciba el voto sepa el motivo, para asi poder corregir dicho error, muchos usuarios en la red tienen esta inquietud asi que con todo respeto tan mal no debo estar, aunque haya algunos que no entiendan

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406901/como-soluciono-el-error-cs1503-argumento-2-no-se-puede-convertir-de-string     a cosas como estas son a las que me refiero, a este usuario alguien le dio un voto negativo, en mi opinión sin ninguna necesidad ya que el fue explícito en su planteamiento, además su planteamiento no exige que el ponga código con lo que pone basta, el que quisiera esclarecerse mejor pues lo hubiera hecho a través de un comentario, a este usuario en vez de ayudarle se le ha espantado

Comment: @Japv Esa pregunta claramente no cumple las reglas de SO(le he dado un DV) ya que no relata correctamente como reproducir su problema, no todos los post necesitan código pero sí un MRE. Por otro lado los DVs no deben asustar a nadie ya que no son votos en contra de la persona sino que muestran que a un usuario no le gusto su post.

Comment: Ahí está el problema eyllanesc le diste el voto negativo y no le explicaste que tenía mal, y si no le explicas esa pregunta va a seguir así ya que el usuario no es adivino, por eso la explicación para que el pueda corregirse, ese voto negativo sin explicación no ayuda al usuario

Comment: @Japv El DV o UV solo tiene como objetivo señalar que a algun usuario no le gusto o le gusto el post, respectivamente, nada más ya que ese tipos de votos no generan otro efecto. A diferencia de los votos de cierre cuyo objetivo es colocar en stand-by una pregunta hasta que el AP la mejore por ello se deben usar motivos específicos. Pienso que estas confundiendo herramientas, por favor usa `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc, sigo estando en desacuerdo, por ejemplo supon tu que un usuario malintencionado con los privilegios suficientes empiece a dar votos negativos a respuestas bien realizadas, hay solucion para esta hipotetica situacion?, el voto negativo debe sustentarse en la opinion de las personas es verdad, pero sigo pensando que hace falta explicarlo, mira como ejemplo el enlace que te puse anteriormente a una pregunta, todavia esa pregunta esta igualita, no ha cambiado pq sencillamente nadie le dijo al usuario como preguntar, ayer fue que vinieron a explicarselo

Comment: Ademas @eyllanesc otro ejemplo, supon que eres estudiante(no se si lo eres actualmente) y realizas un examen, tu crees que saliste bien, pero a la hora de recibir las notas, obtienes una mala nota, acaso no es tu derecho pedirle al profesor que te diga en que te equivocaste, sino lo hace te vas a seguir equivocando en la segunda y tercera convocatoria de esa asignatura, o peor alomejor es el profesor el que se equivoco y te reviso mal y tu en realidad si saliste bien, dime

Comment: @Japv 1) No estoy intentando convencerte ni que estes de acuerdo con mi posición 2) Analicemos tu ejemplo:¿Cuantos usuarios "malintencionados" crees que voten en un post en particular? Pues será uno o a lo mucho dos(en SO tienes que usar el principio de buena fé) ¿qué tanto hace daño a un buen post un par de votos negativo? pues nada ya que si es bueno obtendras más UV. Así que el análisis de los UV o DV no debe ser un analisis de voto por voto sino en el total.

Comment: @Japv [cont.]  Si el post es bueno probablemente tenga 10 UV y 2 DV entonces la comunidad verá: "este post tiene 10 UV vs 2 DV, me parece que vale la pena revisarlo". 3) Respecto al post en particular: Un usuario le comento que revisara las  guias del sitio hace un día y el AP reviso el sitio hace 10 horas y no le respondio nada ¿crees que otros comentarios seràn del interés del AP? Yo pienso que no, al menos el usuario que comento tuvo la intención de ayudarlo pero el AP parece que no tiene el interés en usar la ayuda

Comment: @Japv 4) Estas confundido: SO no es una escuela, universidad, etc. ni los miembros somos docentes. El aprendizaje o enseñanza que generamos es distinto al que busca un profesor o tutor, tenemos menos herramientas y no queremos llegar a tanto. Nuestro unico objetivo es proveer un sitio con preguntas y respuestas de calidad. No somos tutores. Estas sobrevalorando la capacidad del sitio

Comment: Si sería bueno algún feedback (anónimo) en las respuestas. Yo tengo un voto negativo en una respuesta marcada como solución y ni idea de por qué.

Comment: Estuve analizando esta publicación y  la mayoría de los comentarios y vi que si es viable si se utiliza un punto intermedio. Es decir, donde haya un pequeño formulario de opciones a elegir (similar, cuando se reporta una publicación) para indicar el motivo del voto negativo (ya que su objetivo es llamar la atención) y así la persona que publicó su pregunta / respuesta pueda observar un historial estadístico del por qué recibió votos negativos. Mientras tanto, los comentarios se pueden dejar para hacer sugerencia o pedir aclaraciones, así como responder a otros usuarios (cosa que ya sucede).

Comment: Es decir, en lugar de dejar un comentario, seleccionar el motivo del voto, dejando como opcional una opción (valga la redundancia) que diga **Otro motivo.**

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. igualmente hay muchos que no concuerdan

Comment: Asi es, es necesario @Japv. Desde mi punto de vista, es necesario saber los motivos. Se pueden evitar comentarios, pero se pueden marcar los motivos para que se dejen datos estadísticos del por qué recibe votos negativos.

Comment: En mi opinión es necesario de los votos, sobre todo los negativos, sean anónimos, para evitar una vorágine de mal rollo, y obligar a dejar un comentario és contrario a ello.
Por ejemplo, hace poco he obtenido dos votos negativos a dos respuestas aleatorias y asumo que es una "venganza" por contradecir a un usuario en un comentario, y un "formulario" no lo habría impedido .
Piensa que hay gente que le da importancia a eso, y si se conociera quien vota negativo, convertiría SO en un desastre.

Answer (score -1):

La linea que you sigo es que generalmente si veo una pregunta que amerita un downvote le doy el downvote y si veo que es salvable con una edición comento que podría ayudar para mejorar la pregunta, en SO en inglés tenemos la ventaja de poder mandarles el [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  y ya si la pregunta no es salvable de plano le doy su flag

Comment: Aquí también tenemos el enlace de ayuda para leer [ask]