# Porque la gente tiene el dedo tan fácil?

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, código-de-conducta

Me explico.
Mucha gente, y con esto quiero decir que no toda, tiene el dedo muy fácil como para eliminarte, puntuarte negativamente, reportarte ,... una pregunta, entiendo que a veces las preguntas son difíciles de entender, pero siempre tenemos a esa "persona", que se cree soporte del sitio que nos pone el típico texto de :" Puedes leer este Articulo Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida", es entendible hasta cierto punto, pero hay momentos o ciertas preguntas que no se puede poner código, porque es algo que no tiene código, ya que puede ser una configuración o algo por el estilo, la cosa es que ven que no hay código te saltan con eso sin leer ni la pregunta.
Está claro que nadie está obligado a responder, pero encima que te quitan reputación por votar mal tu pregunta, no te responden, y cuando haces el cambio no te quitan la mala reputación.

Es una reflexión que me hago en esta comunidad la cual veo que en vez de querer apoyar y ayudar solo nos queremos pisar para conseguir más reputación que otros.

Comment: Todos formamos parte del soporte del sitio. No hay una persona encargada, hay una comunidad entera encargándose. Sin embargo, si piensas que alguien hizo algo de mas, siempre puedes contactar con el equipo de moderación o dejar un reporte. Vos también formas parte de dicha comunidad, y también podes ayudar a otros a mejorar sus preguntas. No todas las preguntas merecen código, en eso coincido con vos. Sin embargo, si tenes alguna duda con algún caso en particular, compártelo así podemos ayudarte a saber que paso.

Comment: concuerdo con @gbianchi no todas las preguntas ameritan un codigo; sin embargo si un usuario te lo pide; es por que quien quiere ayudarte asi ha determinado que llegara a una solucion mas rapido, eficiente y correcta para los argumentos que presentas. independientemente de lo que digan las normas del sitio la comunidad tomara al final la desicion de que es correcto que cada escenario. saludos buen amigo.

Comment: @gbianchi cierto que todos somos parte del soporte, aquí me equivoqué, más que soporte me refería a moderadores(al fin era una figura con “poder”)  si es cierto que a veces se necesita algo más, pero hoy tube un caso en el que supuestamente la persona que intento ayudarme no hizo un downvote, eso significa que alguien entro hizo downvote, no dijo en que me equivoqué y marcho, a eso me refiero a “poder” a que entro en una pregunta al azar y doy downvote por que si y ya está, no se veo que algo no cuadra

Comment: Concuerdo contigo, llevo poco tiempo en el sitio y esto es una de las cosas que me sorprendió. Las reglas SO son muy ambiguas y alguien nuevo entra hace una pregunta de un modo poco claro y PUM! negativos. Pienso que hay que dar un tiempo prudente para que el autor corrija su pregunta (al menos un par de días). No obstante, también entiendo a los que llevan más tiempo y operan de esa manera, dedicarle tiempo a que una persona corrija su pregunta, para recién dedicarle otro  tiempo para dar una respuesta y para que en muchos caso esa persona ni vuelva es, a lo menos, decepcionante y agotador

Comment: @DavidGonzalo, los votos son secretos, sean positivos o negativos, nunca se puede saber quién los emitió. Entiendo que tus sospechas recaigan sobre quien te comentó en la pregunta, pero nunca pasarán de simples sospechas. Tampoco es "obligatorio" dejar un mensaje o comentario cada vez que se emite un voto, no es como funciona el sitio. Ya de por si la gente vota poco, imagina si les obligaras a dejar un comentario. Supón que fuera obligatorio para los "upvote" también, Las preguntas más votadas tendrían una cantidad igual de comentarios, eso no es nada apetecible ni recomendable. Saludos

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Por qué votan negativo sin dar ninguna explicación al respecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/955)

Comment: Otro relacionado: [Votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4920/votos-negativos). No es la primera vez que se debate este tema.

Comment: @MauricioContreras no digo que no, pero (no digo que lo quiera/vaya ha hacer) es como si fuera dando downvote a cada una de las preguntas que se hace, me parece un poco injusto, entiendo que es así y que así funciona, y que una sola persona no lo va a cambiar, pero es algo que no me parece justo o que podría techarse un ojo ya que una pregunta con downvote no suele llegar tan lejos como una pregunta upvoteada o 0 vote, solo digo que si necesitas ayuda y hacen eso pues se puede hacer eterno

Comment: Los mas viejos, que ya conocemos como funciona esto, ya sabemos a quien votar negativo y cuando.. nos damos cuenta de solo ver los perfiles y las preguntas... Entiendo tu enojo con algunos votos.. pero algunos mas nuevos, que ya tienen permisos para votar, a veces solo votan... igual, todos, todos, tenemos votos positivos y negativos.. un voto, no cambia nada...

Comment: a mi me llovian los votos negativos... tmbien tube sospechas de que los votos de @gbianchi tenian multiplicador (fans)... si el me dejaba uno positivo cain 2 o 3 mas 
 .... si me dejaba uno negativo ... me caian 10 o mas ... despues me entere que no eras asi y que eran puras sospechas y mi mente traicionandome ...

Comment: a lo mejor si lees esto: [¿Por qué votan negativo sin dar ninguna explicación al respecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/955/por-qu%c3%a9-votan-negativo-sin-dar-ninguna-explicaci%c3%b3n-al-respecto) y esto: [Votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4920/votos-negativos) y sigas las indicaciones, instrucciones de los mas viejos... puede que recibas mas votos positivos que negativos... como te lo han dicho antes.

Comment: Deje de justificar mis votos negativos, pues la censura rápidamente los elimina. Eso explica la falta de explicación. Como ahora.

Comment: @CandidMoe tal vez tus explicaciones sean un poco "rudas"? Yo suelo justificar por los demás y esos comentarios nunca fueron borrados.

Comment: @gbianchi los votos negativos pueden resultar en que bloqueen tu cuenta de preguntar. No es facil salir de ese bloqueo. Asi que si, un voto lo cambia todo.

Comment: Entendiendo que el voto es personal, pero a mi igual me resulta raro. Por ejemplo tienes a https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/558049/301324 Que creo realizó una pregunta valida, pero tiene una imagen, el primer negativo le llego casi instantáneo (ahora lleva -4). Luego tienes a https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/558080/301324 que puso un código, pero el código es para aparentar que ha hecho algo y tiene cero votos. Entonces me da la impresión que hay personas ven una imagen y presionan el negativo instintivamente

Comment: @Yussef So en español tiene una fuerte carga horario.. a veces, dependiendo el horario, una pregunta es mas o menos vista.. tambien, depende de los lenguajes...

Comment: @DanteS. son muchos votos en muchas preguntas... si luego de X preguntas, seguis sin hacer caso y haciendo las cosas mal, que esperas que se haga?

Comment: No digo que el sistema este mal. Solo digo que un voto si influye.

Comment: claro que los votos influyen es el sistema de recompensa y la moneda de pago en este sitio... solo con votos recojes reputacion que alimenta tu perfil ...

Comment: @Yussef el problema en esta pregunta  es.stackoverflow.com/q/558049/301324 que dices le metieron - 4; este post no tenia esa imagen mira las ediciones ... era una pregunta sobre codigo sin codigo y el usuario sube ahora una imagen ... no hizo caso de que pala lo mandara a leer el centro de ayuda. y lo que pala le dijo no incluye que existe una MRE a presentar, entonces que quieres que hagamos con este usuario??? hay otros que te mandan a la v3rg4 por decirles como hacer mejor o bien las cosas ... antes que editar sus preguntas ... y ahora el problema con la imagen y el codigo

Comment: @Yussef personalmente he emitido de voto de cierre a esa pregunta, por que no puedo tomar una imagen para reproducir su error/escenario, y por que si el usuario no tiene el tiempo para entender las herramenta del sitio; por que yo debo usar mi tiempo para transcribir su codigo ... no tiene sentido ... el que necesita ayuda o quiere aprender ... debe poner el 200% de su parte para conseguirlo ... y no venir a quejarce de las reglas.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Fíjate bien en las horas de las ediciones y comentarios, yo cuando le comenté, creo recordar que ya tenía -1.  Pienso que pueden haber casos donde el OP hace una pregunta valida pero tiene algún problema (ej: Una imagen), y le caen un par de negativos por eso. Quizás el OP siente que su pregunta fue mal recibida y se va para siempre. Entiendo que también hay otros casos , como el que pone una imagen del enunciado de una tarea (a esos los pasaría por una moledora de carne). Y creo que ahí viene la reflexión (que no es crítica) ¿se está siendo gatillo fácil con los negativos?

Comment: @gbianchi Entiendo lo del horario, sé que los votos negativos de una pregunta no son los mismos que de otra. Pero ciertamente existe un criterio dispar, y me parece que SO tiene reglas poco clara al respecto, no existe una pauta a seguir. Entonces se transforma en que ni las preguntas ni las respuestas puedes ser subjetivas, pero si los votos. Pienso que quizás una alternativa sería bloquear los votos negativos a preguntas (para los usuarios que somos de menos rango) dentro de las primeras 24h

Comment: Pero.. pero.. @Yussef votar negativamente es un privilegio!!! si lo ganaste, bien por vos... nadie puede votar negativamente porque si... tienes que ganartelo.. tanto para preguntas como para respuestas... o vos queres que no votemos negativo a alguien que pone un enunciado por ejemplo? porque es su primera pregunta? yo cuando entro a un sitio nuevo, por lo menos trato de entender como funciona. Imaginate mandas tu primer PR a una libreria sin leer antes las reglas de la misma.. te van a llover las quejas o te van a ignorar.. no? pues es lo mismo...

Comment: @gbianchi es lo que digo acabo de a=hacer otra pregunta, y downvote y sin explicación del porque
pregunta:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/559102/ordenar-los-archivos-de-este-directorio-alfab%c3%a9ticamente
Lo peor de todo que me ha aparecido un mensaje que tengo muchos downvotes y que se me va a quitar el privilegio de preguntar

Comment: Fijate que ahi tenemos otro problema... Alguien contesto tu pregunta, pero ni siquiera penso que estaba bien formulada como para darle un upvote. Tu cuenta no tiene ningun patron reconocible de problemas. Supongo que quien la voto negativo (y es mi suposicion) penso que no habias intentado nada... pero es solo mi suposicion... @DavidGonzalo

Comment: @gbianchi, es a lo que me refería desde un inicio, que en una pregunta medio bien formulada, alguien decidió darle downvote sin ayudar a saber que motivo es el de esa votación, y ahora yo estoy en riesgo de quedarme sin poder preguntar por cumulo de downvote, (otra cosa es, como puedo saber eso?)

Comment: Dudo que llegues a ese punto. Pero bueno, no es posible saber quien te voto. Asi que no es posible saber que paso.

Answer (score 5):

Nota: Sobre la parte de "preguntas que no puede agregarsele código" no puedo decir nada, pues nunca he notado lo que describes.

Esto fue debatido muchas veces, no solo aquí, si no en el sitio en inglés. Incluso me pelee con el meta de area 51 (esos no me explicaron la causa de los votos negativos hasta que lo pedí en otra pregunta. Me caen mal...).

#### Aclaración sobre las preguntas

No todas las preguntas de baja calidad lo son por que "falta código". A veces es por que falta una demostración de que sos parte del esfuerzo por responder la pregunta. Por ejemplo una demostración sería una lista de algunos de los links que visitaste. No digo que la persona detras no se haya esforzado, si no que no lo demuestra.

#### Reputación

Los que compiten por reputación, lo cual no creo que pase con la mayoría, supongo que solo lo harán por poder dentro del sitio y la buena sensación de ganar algo. Pues la verdad, eso es lo unico que te da la reputación aquí.

Además, ten en cuenta que nadie gana reputación moderando el sitio. Es más, los votos negativos hasta cuestan reputación.

Así que hay poco motivo para pisar a otros para ganar más reputación.

#### Por que dar explicaciones

Yo estoy de acuerdo, me parece injusto que no se deje una explicación ante los votos negativos, de cierre y reportes. Yo hago eso, esperar dos dias y luego votar el cierre de la pregunta si no cambió luego de que dejaran un comentario (aunque generalmente, termina cerrada antes de eso).
Pues está bueno darle al otro la oportunidad de mejorar sus preguntas / respuestas y que así la persona haya contribuido al sitio o, al menos, salga ganando algo de manera justa. Pues esta persona podría, por ejemplo, realmente haberse esforzado, o pide recomendaciones u opiniones. Simplemente no sabe como hacer una buena pregunta o como funciona el sitio por x motivo. Y orientarlo es algo humano.
Hasta diría que los votantes negativos deberían recibir notificaciones por las preguntas que votaron negativo para decidir, si quieren, si la pregunta ya no merece el voto negativo.

Peeero...

#### Por que NO dar explicaciones

Es verdad que dejar un comentario lleva su tiempo (incluso los predefinidos) y hacer esas cosas es mantener el sitio con preguntas de calidad. Sin embargo, yo propuse y fue aceptado agregar una pagina en el centro de ayuda "[por que he recibido un voto negativo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)". Eso significa que, con leer el centro de ayuda, ya tendrían una buena pagina para entender por que recibieron los votos negativos y de cierre. Supongo que estas cosas influyen para decir simplemente "leete el centro de ayuda" o votar negativo directamente.

Y a veces, dejar un comentario no funciona, el op (probablemente) termina ignorando aquellos comentarios que son para ayudarlo a que su pregunta sea mejor recibida, incluso cuando se lo comunicas explicitamente. No todos vienen aqui a aprender y a encontrar soluciones a sus problemas, algunos solo buscan gente que le haga "zafar" de una tarea o trabajo. Un ejemplo justamente es la gran mayoría de preguntas que consisten totalmente en el enunciado de un ejercicio (creeme, se nota cuando es así, u solo he estado aquí dos años). En ellas dejar un comentario al OP no suele tener efecto.
Y quizá, eso influye en decir "para que dejar un comentario o decir algo complejo si es probable que este tipo me ignore".

#### Pues... Que hacemos ahora

Bueno, la perspectiva que ganó fue la de dejar que la gente haga lo que quiera, si quiere dejar un comentario que lo haga, si no, que pueda dar el negativo e irse (aunque hay regulaciones, no se puede tirar negativos como confeti). Lo que nos queda es adaptarnos a eso, no hay de otra.

Para tu escenario particular, te recomiendo leerte bien el [centro de ayuda sobre preguntas](/help/asking), sobre todo "[por que he recibido un voto negativo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)" (aplica también a votos de cierre) para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas. Creeme, es muy informativo.

Comment: te falto mencionar que si alguien hace votos negativos consecutivos ... el mismo sistema los elimina, los corrije, ya que detecta el abuso de la herramienta. por todo lo demas tienes mi completo apoyo... gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Gracias! Y de nada! No me centre en el tema ya que en realidad no es relevante para la respuesta, pero utilizo esta expresión al final: "aunque hay regulaciones, no se puede tirar negativos como confeti"

Answer (score 2):

Yo también tengo algunos "conflictos" con lo que pasa en el sitio... por ejemplo se ha vuelto  "ley" llamar "moderadores" a los miembros de la comunidad que tienen poderes especiales y son identificados con un diamante, para colmo incluso se muestra texto Moderador a un lado del diamante. Esto me causa conflicto porque una de las cosas que hace diferente a este sitio es que es moderado por los miembros de la propia comunidad con base en un sistema de privilegios basados en puntos de reputación, esto es tan importante para la operación del sitio que han habido otros sitios de la red de Stack Exchange que han sido cerrados por falta de moderación.

No queda otra que valorar si el sitio (tecnología y comunidad) es suficiente, si es así, pues hay que perseverar en la mejora propia y de la comunidad.

Lo anterior lo menciono porque el asunto de incluir o no código en todas las publicaciones, a mi parecer, es uno de tantos temas en los que es imposible llegar a un consenso en el sentido estricto de *"Acuerdo o conformidad en algo **de todas las personas** que pertenecen a una colectividad"*. Si se encuentra cerrada una pregunta propia o no, sin código, que a tu parecer es una buena pregunta, lo primero es votar para su reapertura. Si esto tarda o es rechazado, abre una discusión específica aquí en Meta o bien haz un reporte para que el caso sea revisado por los moderadores con privilegios especiales.

Otra situación es que el modelo del sitio está pensado en manejar un volumen alto de publicaciones por lo que la retroalimentación principal es por medio de votos y el cierre de preguntas generalmente se hace con unos pocos mensajes genéricos. El recibir comentarios o un mensaje de cierre muy específico es posible. Cuando ocurra lo justo sería apreciar la generosidad de quien lo provee en particular si ha sido útil acorde a las guías de comportamiento.

Comment: me ha gustado tu respuesta en especial por que no sabemos exactamente que privilegios tiene un moderador diamantado y hasta donde llegan sus responsabilidad, a simple vista esto no esta en la ayuda del sitio o no lo he visto en algun post en Meta.

Comment: Tambien quiero mencionar que hay que tomar con pinsas el tema del codigo en las preguntas; si alguien en el sitio con privilegios suficiente puede cerrar, votar o reportar para esta finalidad creo que aparte del mensaje que aggrega el motivo de cierre debe ser conveniente que al momento de emitir el voto exista siempre algun comentario de alguien ... por lo menos de utilidad ... pero es parte de la idiosincracia de la comunidad ...

Comment: yo he cerrado preguntas o apoyado con mi voto donde otro usuario que sabe del tema sugiere la necesidad del codigo para llegar a una correcta solucion.

Comment: en lo que no estoy de acuerdo es en los votos negativos... si ya se sabe que las piblicaciones cerradas seran eliminada, no tiene sentido los votos negativos... incluso si se re-abre una pregunta automaticamente debe de limpiarce esos votos negativos... se supone que se reabrio por que cumplio con las normas minimas del sitio...

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios @ArcanisGK507. Hay un artículo de ayuda sobre los moderadores diamantados, como les digo yo - > [¿Quiénes son los moderadores del sitio, y cuál es su cometido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) y hay otras publicaciones sobre los mismos. Si quieres saber más en lo general o tienes alguna duda específica quizás te pueda ayudar un poco (soy moderador diamantado en Web Applications).

Comment: No todas las publicaciones que han sido cerradas serán eliminadas automáticamente , por ejemplo, una pregunta cerrada, sin comentarios y sin votos positivos será eliminada, pero una pregunta cerrada, con varios comentarios no será eliminada.

Comment: mira, aqui hay un ejemplo de lo que te decia: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/560509/subrayar-el-texto-solo-cuando-el-mouse-pase-por-el-texto

Comment: a quien estoy insultando???